# Can't grab next sibling using css selector within scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to fetch the budget using scrapy implementing css selector within it. I can get it when I use xpath but in case of css selector I'm lost. I can even get the content when I go for BeautifulSoup and use `next_sibling`.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

url = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/"

res = requests.get(url)
sel = Selector(res)
# budget = sel.xpath("//h4[contains(.,'Budget:')]/following::text()").get()
# print(budget)

budget = sel.css("h4:contains('Budget:')::text").get()
print(budget)
```

Output I'm getting using css selector:

```
Budget:
```

Expected output:

```
$25,000,000
```

Relevant portion of html:

```
<div class="txt-block">
            <h4 class="inline">Budget:</h4>$25,000,000
            <span class="attribute">(estimated)</span>
        </div>
```

[website address](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/)

That portion in that site is visible as:
[image]

How can I get the budgetary information using css selector when it is used within scrapy?

Comment: The css selector does not consider tags outside HTML, xpath does.

Answer (score 1):

This selector `.css("h4:contains('Budget:')::text")` is selecting the `h4` tag, and the text you want is in it's parent, the `div` element.

You could use `.css('div.txt-block::text')` but this would return several elements, as the page have several elements like that. CSS selectors don't have a parent pseudo-element, I guess you could use `.css('div.txt-block:nth-child(12)::text')` but if you are going to scrape more pages, this will probably fail in other pages.

The best option would be to use XPath:

```
response.xpath('//h4[text() = "Budget:"]/parent::div/text()').getall()
```

Comment: I've already used an xpath within the above script which is scraping that content flawlessly. I could create a css selector `sel.css(".txt-block:has(> h4:contains('Budget:'))::text").get()` which would do the same as yours but unfortunately scrapy supports very limited pseudo css selectors and that is the reason it will fail.

Comment: As a suggestion, you'd actually want `//h4[etc]/following-sibling::text()[1]` since asking for the `div` will include the `(estimated)` text, too _(which I just noticed the original question did correctly, although commented out)_